# Gradle/Jenkins : Create a gradle file to direct to sub projects

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've got a directory with three android projects in it.
The MainDir looks like that :

```
/.gradle
/.git
/project1
/project2
/project3
.gitignore
.Jenkinsfile
.README.md
```

In jenkins I can't run a shell script during the build that launchs gradle tasks for eauch of those projects because he doesn't know these are projects (he says "no sub-project").

In a project dir it looks like :

```
/.gradle
/app
/build
/gradle
.gitignore
.build.gradle
.gradle.properties
.gradlew
```

Is there a way to make jenkins understand these are three projects he can launch gradle taks in ? Like creating a build.gradle file in the main directory doing that ?
Or should I just create 3 Jenkins items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make three builds in jenkins but unless there is a need to build the libs seperately then it might just end up being extra effort.  Sounds like what you really want is a multi project build [1].  A simple example could sit at the folder above your lib projects as two files, `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`

The `settings.gradle` will define what projects are included in your build's scope.

For example given your `project1`, `project2` and `project3` example your `settings.gradle` may look like this.

```
rootProject.name = 'myRootProjectName'

// note the name is not required to match the actual path
include ":project1"
// but if the name is not the same as the path then we can just
// let gradle know where the project is expected
project(":project1").projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "pathToProject1")

include ":project2"
project(":project2").projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "pathToProject2")

include ":project3"
project(":project3").projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "pathToProject3")

//##### below would be instead of the code above, same thing just manual
// project setup vs letting gradle find the subprojects
// note sometimes you have lots of subprojects in that case it's sometimes
// easier to just use a little logic for finding and setting up the subprojects.
// don't use the code above ##### and below only use one or the other
// or you will have errors.  The method below is the most scaleable since
// adding projects requires zero modifications to the root project
rootProject.name = 'myRootProjectName'

// set up a couple file filters to find the dirs we consider subprojects
FileFilter projectFilter = { File pathname ->
    FileFilter gradleProjectFilter = { File file -> file.name == 'build.gradle' }
    // add this folder if is a directory and that directory contains a build.gradle file
    // here note `File#listFiles` is true if it's `size() > 0` due to
    // groovy's concept of truth (details: http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth)
    return pathname.isDirectory() && pathname.listFiles(gradleProjectFilter)
}

settingsDir.listFiles(projectFilter).each { dir ->
    include ":$dir.name"
    project(":$dir.name").projectDir = dir
}
```

now running `gradle projects` task should show the three submodules.

As for your `build.gradle` file you could specify some common properties to all the modules if needed or just leave the file blank, it must exist but can be empty.  If you wanted to share some configurations then you might set up the `build.gradle` with something like this.

```
project.subprojects { Project subproject ->
    // anything that is defined here will be executed before the subproject's build.gradle file
    subproject.buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            // your private maven repo if needed
            maven { url 'http://1.2.3.4:8081/nexus/content/repositories/release' }
        }
        dependencies {
            // some plugin that is now available to be applied in any subproject
            classpath 'my.sweet.gradle:plugin:0.1'
        }
    }
    subproject.afterEvaluate {
        // this block is executed after the subproject's build.gradle file
        if (project.tasks.withType(org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar)) {
            // for example you might want to set the manifest for each subproject
            manifest {
                attributes 'Implementation-Title': "Lib $subproject.name",
                        'Implementation-Version': version
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[1] https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html